# Determine if path exists as route in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to know if an arbitrary path can be mapped to a route

recognized_request_for accomplishes what I want, but I can't get it to work in my controller.

Specifically, **how can I execute [recognized_request_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html) or something that accomplishes the same task from my controller?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
@related_page_path = '/' + @page.path
begin
  ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(@related_page_path, :method => :get)
rescue
  @related_page_path = nil
end
```

Answer (score 29):

For Rails 3 the call is

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path
```

Instead of

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path
```

Example:

```
def path_exists?(path)
  Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path)
  true
rescue ActionController::RoutingError
  false
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't just be rescuing all Exceptions.

Comment: @PRWhitehead instead of just downvoting and commenting negatively, how about suggesting which exception to rescue?

Comment: You can rescue from ActionController::RoutingError instead

Comment: This doesn't work for redirects in route file unfortunately.

Comment: Small clarification, rescue as used above is an implicit rescue of StandardError not Exception and is not the worst ruby crime you can commit. It conveys no meaning, but won't intercept a CTRL-C etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect an arbitrary path the a controller and and action, you can use `map.connect`

```
map.connect '/any/random/string/of/stuff', :controller => 'items', :action => 'new'
```

You can even call out embedded param designations in the path:

```
map.connect '/seeking/room/for/[:number_of_nights]/nights', :controller => 'rooms', :action => 'index'
```

with the above you will receive the value represented in the url as part of the `params` hash in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across an issue where I had to check if a path existed given an array of possible paths. I had tried the above suggestion `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path`, but it's depericated as of `rails 4.2.1`. I used the following instead:

```
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.routes.any?{ |key, value| key.to_s === "new_article" }
```

Comment: In Rails 5.2.4.8, i'm getting ```private method `routes' called for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::NamedRouteCollection```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly dynamically generate the route helper method and see if it exists (using respond_to? or even just catching any thrown exception).

Comment: yeah, I don't really know what that means :)

Comment: @Cristopher say you are checking this from inside a controller you can use:
`self.respond_to?(:action_name)`. From a helper you can use `controller.respond_to?(:action_name)`. Of course you can also inspect the rail routes with `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.respond_to?(:the_path_you_want_to_check)`