# Rails: link_to only if route exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a Rails Engine and in one of my views I'd like to create a link to main_app if a named route exists.

I will give an example to clarify the question:
The Main application may or may not define in routes.rb:

```
resources :my_resource, only: :index
```

In my rails engine I need to add a link to my_resource_path only if main_app defined that route. I think it should be something like the following:

```
<%= link_to "Link", main_app.my_path if my_resource_path_exists? %>
```

I tried:

```
<%= link_to "Link", main_app.my_resource_path if 
      main_app.respond_to?(:my_resource_path) %>
```

but, when the path does not exist, that raises NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `my_resource_path' for #<Module>
```

How my_resource_path_exists? method could be implemented? I'm using ruby 2.2 and rails 4.2

The question is related to: [Determine if path exists as route in Rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273715/determine-if-path-exists-as-route-in-rails-controller)
But in this case, I have a named route (my_resource_path), so I need something slightly different, but can't figure out by myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if path exists as route in Rails controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273715/determine-if-path-exists-as-route-in-rails-controller)

Comment: I just edit the question to explain the differences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution wich does not require to recover from fail. It's possible to check if the route is defined using url_helpers:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.method_defined?(:my_path)
```

So, the code could be written like that:

```
<%= link_to "Link", main_app.my_resource_path if 
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.method_defined?(:my_resource_path) %>
```

Comment: I like to use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.respond_to?(:what_i_want_to_check_path)`

Comment: Can this handle formats so it only passes if html exists but not json or csv etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use main_app.try(:my_path) or rescue NoMethodError to return false.

Comment: The question is: how to check if the path is defined? I'm writing a mountable engine and would like to optionally add a link to main_app if main_app want to.

Comment: try will attempt to call :my_path, how can I use this to check if the route is defined? Rescue from fail is a possibility, but i will have to write the helper method. I found that I can use: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.method_defined? :my_path