# Link_to a path only if route exists with Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, conditional-statements

I'm building a table partial *using a custom ´Table´ class with corresponding subclasses) that will generate tables for multiple models of my app. What I'm trying to achieve is making a table row link to a show page but since not all the models have a show page, the linking needs to be conditional.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904557/rails-link-to-only-if-route-exists) but unfortunately the answers suggested there don't seem to work for me.

Here the relevant code:

```
%tbody
  - @table.rows.each do |row|
    %tr
      -row.attributes.each do |cell|
        %td.clickable-cell
          = link_to cell, polymorphic_url(row.object)
```

When I added `if Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.method_defined?(polymorphic_url(row.object))` or `if Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.respond_to?(polymorphic_url(row.object))` condition the link doesn't get generated at all, not for the pages with, nor without a show.

When no condition applied, and the link is clicked for models without a show page, I get a `Routing Error No route matches`.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904557/rails-link-to-only-if-route-exists they can also be get to checked paths?

Comment: You can add a condition to displaying the `link_to` only `if row.object.class.in?([Foo, Bar, Baz])`

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn: Sorry, didn't understand what you mean in that comment. could you rephrase?

Comment: Sorry @SergioTulentsev, autocorrect. According to that Stack question these methods can also be used to check if a path exists. I guess my error was that I assumed that my `polymorphic_url(row.object)` would be equivalent to let's say `:user_path`(as they generate the same html), which apparently is not the case.

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn: yes, that was exactly your error.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong

Yes, of course. `method_defined?` and `respond_to?` accept a method name (like `:user_path`), not a url (`http://example.com/users/1`).

> and how to fix it?

You could try something like this:

```
if Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.respond_to?("#{object.model_name.singular_route_key}_path")
```

For a `User`, this will return `user_path`.

Comment: It should be `object.class_name.underscore.downcase` ?

Comment: @Gabbar: right, need the underscore for names like `MyVehicle`

Comment: This is a good approach, but it would be better to use `row.object.model_name.singular_route_key` instead of `object.class.name.downcase'.

Comment: @WizardofOgz: absolutely, I _knew_ there should be something in rails.

Comment: @WizardofOgz: although this could fail for STI models. Like, if we have `Vehicle::Truck < Vehicle`, this will get us `vehicle_truck_path`, but in reality vehicles are all accessible via `vehicle_path`. But hey, we're only showing the direction here, right? :)

Comment: I'm sorry guys but this approach does not prevent link generation for models without a show, it's behaving exactly as if I had no condition at all.

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn: must be you're doing something wrong. Works on my machine. Check that your object gets you the correct method name.

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.respond_to?('foo_bar_path') # => false` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn: ah, this check might fail when you don't have a `show` but have, say, `update`. It's the same route name. At this point, I would resort to manually annotating my models. Minimal implementation could look like this:  `class User; HAS_SHOW_ROUTE = false; end` and then `if object.class::HAS_SHOW_ROUTE`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, I realised it had to be my `delete` methods that were returning the method `true`. Is there a way pass something like `method: :get` to these helpers? Have a lot of models and the app is growing too so manual annotation, although it is the only thing that worked so far, seems like a painful workaround.

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn: I don't know of such a way :/